# Command-Binding (with RelativeSourceExtension) within a StackLayout using BindableLayout.ItemsSource

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, relativesource

I am trying to bind a command (with RelativeSourceExtension) to a button within a StackLayout using BindableLayout.ItemsSource in an Xamarin.Forms App.

**Not working version of MyControl.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      ...
      x:Class="MyApp.Views.MyControl">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                 BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <Button Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MyControl}}, Path=BindingContext.RemoveCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                Text="Remove"/>
    </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

Unfortunately the button is "inactive" and does not let you "click".
The same command binding works fine in a ListView with ItemsSource.

**Working version of MyControl.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      ...
      x:Class="MyApp.Views.MyControl">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
              HasUnevenRows="true">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MyControl}}, Path=BindingContext.RemoveCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                            Text="Remove"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Control Usage in MainPage.xmal:

```
<Grid BindingContext="{Binding Cart}">
    ...
    <views:MyControl/>
    ....
</Grid>
```

Am I generally doing something wrong? Or is there a trick to make this work?

Comment: By inactive you mean it just doesn't respond or does it also look different? Where is this extension coming from?

Comment: Yes, it looks different too. On iOS without styling it is black - not blue like "working" buttons.
RelativeSourceExtension or RelativeSource it does not matter. It is the official Extension from Xamarin.Forms.Xaml (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.xaml.relativesourceextension)

Comment: Where is an instance of `MyControl` in your XAML? Since the button is bound to this, I'd argue that this was crucial to your issue. Could you show XAML up to the root? You can leave out the bits that are definitely irrelavant, but this is not suffient, I think.

Comment: In the updated post, is the relevant content of the control and the usage in the App.

Comment: @Christoph Why do not you use the custom control directly?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom control directly"?

Comment: @Christoph I misunderstand your description. Could you provide the command details? I could not reproduce and need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You missed using StackLayout.ItemTemplate and after DataTemplate in you xaml. Your button is not wrapped in a good way. That's it.